# QuerySelector for Web Elements Inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Edit: New title.
What I'm looking for is a document.querySelector for elements inside an iframe.

I've done quite a bit of Googling for an answer and finally I'm stumped.

I'm trying to query inside an iframe. I'm building string selectors to be used in Selenium and usually I just inspect the element with Firebug, and use document.querySelectorAll("theStringIBuid");

But it doesn't work with elements inside iframes. I've tried all of the below to get an element "radiobutton1" inside the "page-iframe" iframe.

```
var elem1 = ".page-iframe";
console.log(elem1);
var elem2 = ".radiobutton1";
console.log(elem2);
document.querySelectorAll(elem1+elem2+"");

document.querySelectorAll('.page-iframe').contentWindow.document.body.querySelectorAll('.radiobutton1')
document.getElementById('.page-iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('.page-iframe'), 
function  fn(elem){ 
console.log(elem.contentWindow.document.body.querySelectorAll('.radiobutton1')); });

var contentWindow = document.getElementById('.page-iframe').contentWindow 
var contentWindow = document.querySelectorAll('.page-iframe') 
var contentWindow = document.querySelectorAll('.page-iframe')[0].contentWindow
```

Thanks-

Comment: Are you maybe running the script before the iframe is done loading? What do you get if you console.log the contentWindow?

Comment: If you're using selenium you will need to call switchTo().frame("id of frame") then run your code.

Comment: Well I've been working on this for two hours now so I think the page is done loading :)

Comment: And I'm not using Selenium to write the query, I'm trying to write the query in Firebug console. Any idea how to write a console query to access elements inside an iframe?

Answer (score 77):

simple es6 adapted from [h3manth](https://h3manth.com/content/get-iframe-contents-using-queryselectors):

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach( item =>
    console.log(item.contentWindow.document.body.querySelectorAll('a'))
)
```

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxx.xxx.xx" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.", source: https://xxx.xxx.xx/#!/ (1)

Comment: are you sure the domain in and out the iframe are the same?

Comment: I don't know about Selenium, but with puppeteer you can pass "--disable-web-security" in the launch args and access cross-origin frames.

Comment: Just sharing an working example with typescript: document.getElementById("...")['contentWindow'].document.querySelectorAll("..."). Ty!

Comment: Seems like more often then not the iframe does not have the same URL.

Comment: related: to access the shadow DOM of a custom element, you would use `elem.shadowRoot` instead of `iframe.contentWindow.document`

Answer (score 45):

if the original page's url isn't at the same domain with the iframe content, the javascript will treat the iframe as a black box, meaning it will not see anything inside it.

Comment: That is right. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Answer (score 33):

You can do this:

```
document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector("button")
```

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-mNp3-UX9Qc

Comment: Why `contentWindow.document` and not just `contentDocument`?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use

```
document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument.body.querySelector("#btn")
```

First query selector is to select the iframe. Then we can access ifram dom using content document and use the 2nd query selector to select the element inside iframe.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality. You should add some text to your answer explaining what you're doing and why it works.

Comment: You need to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet for diving into same-origin frames (ie-compatible ES5):

```
function findInFramesRec(selector, doc) {
  var hit = doc.querySelector(selector);
  if (hit) return hit;
  var frames = Array.prototype.slice.call(doc.frames);
  for(var i = 0; (i < frames.length) &&   !hit   ; i++) {
    try {
      if (!frames[i] || !frames[i].document) continue;
      hit = findInFramesRec(selector, frames[i].document);
    } catch(e) {}
  }
  return hit;
}
```

This dives into both frameset frames and iframes alike. It may even survive (though not enter) cross origin frames.