# setting the playback rate of html5 video in html

Tags: html, html5-video

When watching a video, its possible to enter developer mode in the browser and enter the following command in the console to change the playback speed of a video

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].playbackRate = 0.9
```

When I try however to code this in html I am unable to access the video object.

```
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
console.log(obj);
```

returns an object of length 0

also trying

```
var player1 = document.getElementById("video");
console.log(player1);
player1.playbackRate = 2;
```

returns **null**

A demo of the not working code so far is here:
https://jsbin.com/peludojisi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Can someone please help me figure out how to set the playbackRate from html

many thanks in advance

Jesse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelector` does not work across `iframe`s. Since the video in your example is within an iframe, your query returns null.

The error message in you snippet tells you almost as much:

> "TypeError: Cannot set property 'defaultPlaybackRate' of null
>       at :16:59

Line 16 of your script:

> ```
>   document.querySelector('video').defaultPlaybackRate = 2.0;
> ```

Comment: indeed, this line fails. I am wondering how the browser console is able to run the query and work despite the iframes

Comment: Querying does not include iframe contents, regardless of whether you're using the browser dev console or querying from a script on the page.

Comment: there seems to be someway to query the contents of iframes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630519/queryselector-for-web-elements-inside-iframe

Comment: I realize now that searching inside the iframe isn't possible due to the it being generated on another domain.