# Inconsistent results from document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

I opened the Chrome development console pane and evaluated this expression:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.fc-event-inner")).filter(e => {
  let r = e.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (r.left < 1354) && (r.top < 531) && (r.right > 1167) && (r.bottom > 487);})
```

It returned an empty array.

Then I used the "Select an element in the page to inspect it" button in the development pane to click on an element and see my element expanded in the element list. Then I re-evaluated the same expression and it returned an array of 2 elements even though nothing on the page had moved. Why am I getting inconsistent results?

BTW, I probably should have simplified the question. I think the same is true when I simply evaluate

```
document.querySelectorAll("div.fc-event-inner")
```

[image: Recording of the problem]

*Edit:* I am trying to evaluate the contents of each IFrame before running my target querySelectorAll. When I evaluate this expression, things are OK, but I still don't get any updated results:

```
document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.childElementCount
```

But when I try to evaluate this condition:

```
document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[1].contentWindow
```

Chrome has a rather hard error (STATUS_BREAKPOINT):
[image: Chrome page error]
[image: Chrome Dev Tools error]

I am able to circumvent this error using eval, but I find that the content of the iframe is blank:

```
eval("document.querySelectorAll(\"iframe\")[1].contentWindow.document.body.outerHTML")
```

Result: "<body></body>"

Comment: Could you show us some HTML?

Comment: I think the HTML I'm working with is too complex to share.

Comment: Ok. Are you sure the elements had loaded by the time you evaluated the expression?

Comment: @Rojo I was looking at the elements in question on the screen when I evaluated the expression. They must have been loaded.

Comment: If the HTML is too complex, create a simpler version that displays the problem and post that. See [mcve]

Comment: Could be that some timered events or focus events are modifying the DOM between your evaluations

Comment: Could you share a video of the process you mentioned? (Maybe a gif so that it loads fast?)

Comment: I suspect it's related to the fact that this element is embedded in an iframe. I think I'm looking for some confirmation that document content in embedded iframes is not evaluated until some condition is met and how to force that condition to be met.

Comment: Use onload on the IFrame?

Comment: I can't edit the HTML document. I'm writing automated tests to test web site content.

Comment: @Rojo video added.

Comment: Can you find the elements through inspect element before using any tools?

Comment: @Rojo Inspect element *is* the tool I used in that demo to cause it to become visible isn't it?

Comment: Ok. So that means you are 100% sure that whatever you're selecting has that class and is a `<div>`?

Comment: @Rojo I didn't hit my target with the mouse in that demo. I suspect all that really needs to happen is that I select any element within the IFrame (which necompasses most of the page) and then everything in the document suddenly becomes available to document.querySelectorAll.

Comment: Ohhhh it's in an iFrame. [How about try it like this the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630519/queryselector-for-web-elements-inside-iframe/28778893)

Comment: @Rojo Interestingly enough I am also using Selenium! I'll give it a try; thanks. If it works what should I do with this question? Answer it with my specific solution, or close it like a duplicate?

Comment: Use your specific solution if it isn’t exactly the same as the other question. You should reference the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing content within an IFrame poses unique challenges. To access the content from JavaScript, it's necessary to first access the correct IFrame. For example:

```
eval("document.querySelector(\"iframe\").contentDocument.querySelector(\"iframe\").contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll(\".fc-event-inner\")")
```

The `eval` is necessary to avoid a Chrome error that occurs as soon as the development tools pane tries to evaluate and highlight the inner frame while you type. The `eval` prevents the real-time evaluation and highlighting.

If using Selenium, this seemed to be working for me:

```
var f = switchTo.frame(0)
var banners = f.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.fc-event-inner"))
Utilities.actionLog("Banners: " + banners.size)
```