# How to run script only if div:contains in an iFrame - Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, iframe, greasemonkey

So let's say we have this code in an iFrame. I'm pretty sure the iFrame is from the same domain, that matters I think.

```
<div id="10">You become 1 best coder</div>
```

I want a Greasemonkey script which will run a script only if both "div id=10" and the text (or part of the text) is true.

I tried this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Script
// @include     https://www.somesite.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

var intv = setInterval(function() {
    
    const sp = document.querySelector('#10'); // find id (some)
if (sp && sp.textContent === 'You become 1 best coder') {

alert('Hello world!');
    
    }

      }, 5000);
```

And this works on a regular page with regular content. But when the content I need the script to identify in order to run loads inside an iFrame, the script doesn't run.

Here is an example of the iFrame code:

```
<iframe src="something.php?text=M0000310y100g190e500A78014607601&amp;lalala=tT6&amp;ctrl=032a4c3342e76e97ea21821a5c5f800e&amp;mamama=c2ed5535532cc20aef064db2b4" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I assume the iFrame is from the same domain, because if it was from a different domain the src="" would be different, I think...

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the `iframe`. If that is the only one then you can try ....

Note: Updated based on comment

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Script
// @include     https://www.somesite.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

const intv = setInterval(function() {
  const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src*="something.php"]');
  const sp = iframe && iframe.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('#10'); // find id (some)
  if (sp && sp.textContent === 'You become 1 best coder') {
    alert('Hello world!');
  }
}, 5000);
```

**Update**

iframe content are also document. If the code doesn't need to interact with the parent frame, you can inject the userscript in the target iframe document and run it there.

Comment: I tried it on Firefox 55.0.2 and 74.0.1, but it didn't work. I used inspect element and my div is located in iframe>body>div. There are also other iFrames on the page, but they're inside of the main iframe. Any ideas?

Comment: In Firefox 55.0.2 (which is where I'd like to use the script) I ran the script in the console - const sp = document.querySelector('iframe')?.contentWindow.document.body.querySelector('#10');
  if (sp && sp.textContent === 'You become 1 best coder') {
    alert('Hello world!');
  } - and I got this error - SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'

Comment: I said that Optional chaining is for FF74+. If there are more iframes, then you have to find the right one. I will update the code.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad I should have mentioned in my opening post that I want it to work for Firefox 55. It's an important piece of information, just completely slipped my mind. Do I have to find the right iFrame even if the other iFrames are inside of the one main iFrame?