# Chrome extension using document.querySelector can't find YouTube Live Chat messages on first try

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

**What I want to do**

Log all chat messages on YouTube Live Chat onto console. (Forgive me this, as I am just in the first step.)

**What I'm doing**

Using MutationObserver to catch changes to a mount point (`const point`).
[Here's my code so far](https://jsfiddle.net/deeeeekun/291ojrya/).

**How I'm testing**

I copy and paste the above code to the console after loading a YouTube video with chat messages. (Just for reference, I'm testing on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pKfdczvABc))

**What I need help with**

The code can't find the element I'm using as const point and returns null. However, if I search for the element using my browser inspector it is there. Furthermore, running the code again after having searched for it in inspector gives me my desired result. I want to know what is causing this phenomenon.

Comment: The page is dynamically loaded so when you run your code the element isn't there yet. You could use a timeout of X seconds before executing your code.

Comment: @iamdim I jump forward through the video and only paste my code to the console after I have seen the first few chat messages loaded, though

Answer (score 0):

YouTube's live chat is inside an iFrame so I had to query the selector through the iFrame. Details can be found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630519/queryselector-for-web-elements-inside-iframe).